# org-edit-src-code Do not pop a new window, use the current one

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I call `org-edit-src-code` to edit a SRC code on a buffer with the proper major mode, I get a new window configuration.

For example, if I have windows 1|2, `org-edit-src-code` will delete window 2 and split window 1 horizontally.

How can I have `org-edit-src-code` reuse the window from the org file and leave all other windows alone? In other words, I'd like `org-edit-src-code` to work as a narrowing command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the variable `org-src-window-setup`.

It seems that adding the following code to your config file would do what you want:

```
(setq org-src-window-setup 'current-window)
```

There are other options available, which you can list with `M-x describe-variable org-src-window-setup`

Comment: If you are using an emacs bundle (as in doom emacs) that comes bundled with a popup management library, the values in `display-buffer-alist` might get in your way. You can investigate the rules by doing a describe on `display-buffer-alist` variable and search for the buffer name.