# org-edit-src-code in a specific window

Tags: org-mode, window

I am currently using org-mode to edit code blocks for presentations and blog posts.

Currently I have a frame set up with one large window pane on the left, and two smaller panes on the right.

- The bottom right pane is a Python console
- The top right pane is ideally a "target" buffer in Python mode
- The left pane is an editing window for the entire .org document.

Ideally, I would be able to send the code blocks to the "target" pane from the org document (using `C-c '`) while all of the window positions remain static. Unfortunately, org-mode replaces the existing panes with the temporary one when I issue this command.

I have tried setting`(setq org-src-window-setup 'other-window)` in my configuration file. This seems to be close to the desired behavior, but emacs does not seem to know which existing window I want to send the editing block to.

Is there any way to send the code blocks to the target pane (perhaps with `C-c '` or some other command) as described? All other functionality would ideally work the same as `C-c '` (edit the buffer, and send the edited code back to the original code block).

Comment: Check this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35784/org-edit-src-code-do-not-pop-a-new-window-use-the-current-one/35808#35808 It seems that what you need is to add `(setq org-src-window-setup 'other-window)` to your .emacs config file

Comment: I tried this, and it gets me closer. The only issue now is that emacs does not seem to know which "other window" I am referring to and as a result switches from displaying edits in the top right and bottom right frames (thereby over-riding my Python shell every other C-c-')