# Restore wndows after OrgSrc mode

Tags: org-mode, window

I am new to org mode, so it might be a very simple matter, but I couldn't find/figure out it myself.

Say, I have created a few horizontal and vertical windows. Opened an org file which has some source code blocks. Then I wanted to edit one of the blocks by going into `Org-Src` mode using `C-c '` and exiting from it using `C-c '`. First time I enter `C-c '`, all other windows in my frame closes, only the org file window stays and a new window which holds the source blocks opens. This is fine although I would prefer it to utilize some opened window. The 2nd time I use `C-c '` to exit from `Org-Src` mode, the org src window closes, the org file window goes maximized/takes up the full frame. This is what I don't want. When I used `C-c '` the 2nd time, I wanted to exit from `Org-Src` mode and restore my previously opened windows. I looked at manual page of `Org-Src` mode but the only thing I found useful was the hook function, but I don't know how I can utilize that to restore the windows after exiting from org src edit mode.

```
Emacs version - 27.1
Org Mode version - 9.3 (release that comes with emacs itself)
OS - Windows 10 and Linux
```

**Question**: How to restore previous window layout after quitting `org-edit-src-code`(`C-c '`) ?

Comment: Good question! Could you specify `emacs-version` and `org-version` ?  I can't reproduce it with `emacs-version = 28.0.50` (`2020-10-06`) and `org-version = 9.4`.

Comment: As this [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35784/org-edit-src-code-do-not-pop-a-new-window-use-the-current-one?rq=1) suggests, the relevant variable is `org-src-window-setup`. And if you check the documentation (`C-h v`), it says that `Values that modify the window layout (reorganize-frame, split-window-below,
split-window-right) will restore the layout after exiting the edit buffer.` So maybe there is some oddity occurred in your side. Try with `emacs -Q` and load `org-mode` to see if this issue still remains.

Comment: `(setq org-src-window-setup 'current-window)` seems most reasonable to me. Thanks everyone, consider this as solved from my side.